# ssh -X to open a file manager

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I have to machines running Ubuntu 18.10

When ssh -X to another computer

```
  ssh -X assistant@pc.local
```

firefox and google-chrome could be opened at the current machine with firefox

```
firefox  
google-chrome
```

However, if tried to open the files manager with

```
xdg-open .
#or
nautilus .
```

the file manager is launched from the desktop of remote machine rather than the current.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the `--new-window` option for Nautilus:

```
ssh -X remote-machine nautilus --new-window
```

Comment: Otherwise you should kill all Nautilus instances on the remote machine before launch it "locally".

Comment: In cases like this, we don't want to kill `nautilus` in the remote computer. Otherwise this would be an attractive solution, but it does not work for me in 18.04.1 LTS (the remote computer, the server, is running standard Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS). The `nautilus`window is still opened on the remote computer's desktop. Does it work with Ubuntu 18.10?

Comment: @sudodus - Before I posted the answer, I tested it between 2 Ubuntu 18.04 laptops and it worked well. For the purposes of debugging, you could try pa4080's suggestion and kill Nautilus first. Also, check your `~/.ssh/config` file options which may cause this to not work for you.

Comment: Good, it works for you between 2 Ubuntu 18.04 laptops :-) I have not added anything special into my `~/.ssh/config` but still it is failing for me, while `pcmanfm` works without any problems. Anyway, now the OP, @Alice, has two options. If your solution works for her, I will delete my answer, because she wants to run `nautilus`.

Comment: @Alice, I tested with a live session of Ubuntu 18.10 as the remote system, server. I installed `openssh-server` and created a (non-blank) password, which made it possible to log in via `ssh -X`, and this way I managed to get the `nautilus` window in my local desktop (in the client computer). So you will probably succeed according to this answer :-)

Comment: I'm running Wayland (not Xorg) in my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, which acted as server in my test. Maybe this (using Wayland) caused my problem with `nautilus`.

Comment: I hadn't considered the Wayland factor. My successful test was using Xorg on both laptops.

Comment: for terminator `ssh -X hrg@remote-machine terminator`

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have the following options in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then follow the instructions in the [answer above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109543/618353).

[image: sshd_config snapshot]