# SSH: Could not get nautilus GUI on X11

Tags: gnome, ssh, nautilus, xorg

I am `ssh`ing into a Ubuntu 18.04 machine with X11 forwarding from Windows 10 using `PuTTY`and `Xming`. I have successfully connected and I can confirm that X11 Forwarding is working.

To test it, if I run `xclock` command on the remote machine, it successfully shows up the Clock GUI. Also tried `gedit` and everything seems to work just fine.

[image]

But if I run `nautilus` there are no errors are warnings displayed, but nothing shows up. Same goes for `gnome-terminal`. I also tried `nautilus --no-desktop` but it doesn't show any errors either, but doesn't show up. I also [searched](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=nautilus+xming) Askubuntu and looked up this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/933022/nautilus-wont-open-16-04) but it's not clear if the OP got it connected successfully or not.

Is this related to any specific config? How do I get `nautilus` and `gnome-terminal` working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssh -X to open a file manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109531/ssh-x-to-open-a-file-manager)

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109531/ssh-x-to-open-a-file-manager#answer-1109543).  The `--new-window` option is needed.

Make sure that no other Nautilus window is already open on the remote machine.  Else, you'll open Nautilus windows there, and not in your SSH client.